# How to restructure this table to convert all row names to column names?

Tags: r

This is my dataset:

[image]

Which function should I use to change it to four columns with the column names, Revenues, Gross profit, Net income and Year? I just need help with the function and the code, which I just forget how to use. I don't need the final output. Thanks many in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Try this `base R`solution using `t`, which transposes rows into columns and vice versa:

**Solution**:

```
df1 <- t(df)
df2 <- as.data.frame(df1[-1,])
colnames(df1) <- c(df$...1)
```

**Result**:

```
df2
           Revenues Gross profit Net income
year2018  0.1331016   -0.9511485 -1.1987364
year2019 -0.8939590   -0.5610915 -1.6367285
```

**Reproducible data**:

```
df <- data.frame(
  ...1 =c("Revenues", "Gross profit", "Net income"),
  year2018 = rnorm(3),
  year2019 = rnorm(3))
df
          ...1   year2018   year2019
1     Revenues  0.1331016 -0.8939590
2 Gross profit -0.9511485 -0.5610915
3   Net income -1.1987364 -1.6367285
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. First `pivot_longer`, then `pivot_wider`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- tibble( 
  `...1` = c("Revenue", "Gross Profit", "Net income"),
  `2018` = runif(3),
  `2019` = runif(3)
)

df %>% 
  rename(var = 1) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-var, names_to = "Year") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = var, values_from = value)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   Year  Revenue `Gross Profit` `Net income`
#>   <chr>   <dbl>          <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1 2018   0.0735          0.286        0.902
#> 2 2019   0.205           0.551        0.348
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: My pleasure. `rename(var = 1)` renames the first (= 1) column with the ugly name "...1" to "var". This way it's easier to work with.